# use a `for in` loop to alter an objects property with a function

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I'm trying to create a function that goes through an objects properties and multiplies the values by 2 if that value is a number.

I'm sure the `var value` is an integer but it's not applying the multiplication ? Where am I going wrong in this code ?

```
var menu = {
width: "200",  
height: "300",
title: "My menu"
};

function multiplyNumeric(menu) {

 for(var key in menu) {
    var value = menu[key];
    if( typeof value === 'number' ) {
        value = value * 2;

    }
 }

}

multiplyNumeric(menu);

alert(menu.width);
```

Comment: there is no `number` in `menu`. Because of the quotes, all your properties are strings. You could use `parseInt` or remove the quotes

Comment: If you don't want to use parseInt use + as unary operator as 
var numberAsString= '5';
var stringAsNum = +numberAsString;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers (as well as strings and booleans) are passed by value. You're copying the value the a new variable where you're modifying it.

You need to modify the object's property directly:

```
for (var key in menu) {
  if (typeof menu[key] === 'number') {
    menu[key] *= 2;
  }
}
```

Also, JavaScript will not return `"number"` if you ask for `typeof("200")`; it will return `"string"`. You need a numeric literal, not a string:

```
var menu = {
  width: 200,  
  height: 300,
  title: "My menu"
};
```

Comment: If those string should be valid, something like `if( Number(menu[key])==menu[key] ) { menu[key] *=2; }` could be used. This for sure would not work with `+=`.

Comment: @meagar I don't quite understand why the `var value` won't work here ? Shouldn't it transfer the altered data to the value going through the `for in` loop ?

Comment: @moonshineOutlaw No, because you're copying the value to a new variable. If I do `x = 1; y = x; y =  y + 1`, I'm not altering `x` at all. `x` is still `1`, and `y` is now `2`. This is a fundamental property of variables. When you assign one to another, you're assigning the **value**, not a reference to the variable. Note that, for objects, the value being assigned is a reference to the object (again, *not* a reference to the variable).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the those strings to numbers in your object:

```
var menu = {
  width: 200,  
  height: 300,
  title: "My menu"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your object as follow dont use quotes for number at your object

```
var menu = {
width:200,  
height:300,
title: "My menu"
};
```